# Can't enter on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-debugger

I'm facing a problem with a jquery script. Can't enter on an if statement.

Can someone explain me why I cant enter on `if (partner_type_id === 1)` even if the value is 1?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#holder_0_partner_nr').change(function(){

        var partner_type_id = $("#holder_0_partner_type_id").val();
        var partner_nr = $("#holder_0_partner_nr").val();

        console.log(partner_type_id);
        console.log(partner_nr);

        if (partner_type_id === 1)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('sgc.contracts.create.get.occ.person.data') }}',
                type: 'get',
                data: { partner_nr: partner_nr },
                success: function(response) {

                    if (response !== false)
                    {
                        let data = JSON.parse(response);

                        $("#holder_0_name").val(function() {
                            return data.name;
                        });

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `console.log("1" === 1)`

Comment: `$("#holder_0_partner_type_id").val()` will return a numeric String, not a number.

Comment: `===` includes type checking. Confirm if its a number?

Comment: if (Number(partner_type_id) === 1)

Comment: Thanks for all the help... It was returning string and I was comparing to a number.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it is a number? try parseInt(partner_type_id) === 1  OR partner_type_id === '1'?

Answer (score 1):

[.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val) can return a number, string or array

In this case:

`if (partner_type_id === 1)` with [triple ===](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)(strict check), will only be true if both the value and type is equal.

Since you're comparing to a number you must make sure `partner_type_id` is also a number and not a string containing "1".

Either parse your variable correctly or use double ==

Comment: You can use parseInt(partner_type_id, 10) to convert that to a number